# Google will render but not index my SPA site

Tags: seo, single-page-application, react-js

I have a single-page-app / website built with React JS, where Google will only index my index page. All the other URL's in my sitemap are recognised, but either marked with `Discovered - currently not indexed` or `Crawled - currently not indexed`.

Testing with `Fetch as Google` shows that they render just fine without a problem. And they have all have their own title, description and canonical meta tags.

So what could possibly cause this?

Comment: If you do a `site:` search do you find your pages?

Comment: To get your pages indexed you need to link to them.   It isn't sufficient just to include them in a sitemap.

Comment: If I do a `site:` search, only the index page shows up, as expected.
All pages have links to them. I don't see why this question is marked as duplicate. The threads referenced has little to do with my issue here. Which is that Google are perfectly able to render the page, all pages have canonical tags, are being linked to, as well as having the sitemap to help Google out further.